# Ruby shared variable between files

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to make a CSV importer in Ruby with a progress bar. The problem is that **SiteController** does not see ProgressBar's variables initialized. How can I do it properly? I need to be able to access variables in the controller. But why it cannot work using include?

```
class SpecificImporter < Importer

    include ProgressBar
    def import
        ....
        custom logic
        Thread.new do 
        @rows.each do |r|
        increment_bar
        end
    end
end

class Importer 
    attr_accessor :file
    include ProgressBar

    def calculate_max_rows
        l = File.open(@file.path).count
        set_max_rows(l)
    end
end

module ProgressBar
    attr_reader :cur,:max

    def increment_bar
        @cur += 1
    end
    def set_max_rows(val)
        @max = val
    end

    def progress
        @cur / @max
    end

end

class SiteController < ApplicationController
    include ProgressBar
    def update_progress
        ..
        #send data using json every x seconds
        ..
        status = progress
    end

end
```

Comment: Note that it shouldn't be necessary for `SpecificImporter` to `include ProgressBar` because the parent class has already done that.

Comment: Additionally,  things like `set_max_rows` are very much against the spirit of Ruby. If you want to be able to write to that attribute, use `attr_accessor` which gives you the `max=` method. For clarity you might want to call that attribute `max_rows` so you can do `self.max_rows = l` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The module is just a chunk of methods and variables. It doesn't provide you a storage that you can use between your `Importer` class and the `SiteController`. It's just provides you an ability to define equal methods in several classes which are not inherited from each other. It's something like Mixin pattern (take a look at this description: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixin).

To "share variable between files" you should use something similar to Redis or Memcached. The regular SQL DB can provide this functionality too, but it won't be so effective in this case =)

Take a look at this guide to understand how it should be working: https://www.sitepoint.com/introduction-to-using-redis-with-rails/

So here's a little improvement of yours example to make it clear (even more better solution would be to implement counters in redis or update it's value on every 10th step or so to decrease load on redis. But it's a complication)):

```
module ProgressBar
  attr_accessor :curr, :max

  def increment_bar
    @curr += 1
    save_progress # <- Save progress on each step
  end

  def progress
    @curr / @max
  end

  def save_progress(process_id)
    $redis.set("progress_#{process_id}", progress)
  end

  def load_progress(process_id)
    $redis.get("progress_#{process_id}") || 0
  end
end

class Importer
  include ::ProgressBar

  def calculate_max_rows
    # some logic will go here...
    set_max_rows(l)
  end
end

class SpecificImporter < Importer
  def import
    # custom logic...
    increment_bar
  end
end

class SiteController < ApplicationController
  include ProgressBar
  def update_progress
    # some logic here...
    status = load_progress(params[:process_id]) # <- Load stored progress
  end
end
```